# Keprekar numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, split

I'm trying to solve Kaprekar numbers in C++.
The algorithm is pretty simple:

- Take an interval from a to b, for example 1 to 100
- 0 < a < b < 100000
- Take a variable x and assign it element^2
- You have to split x, let's say we have the element 45 from interval 10 to 100 and we'll have 45^2 = 2025. That means you have to split 2025 into 2 parts and the sum of that two parts equals to x. That means you must take 20 and 25 -> 20+25 = 45.
- Both splitted parts must be non-negative integers.
- Print all the elements from that interval which respect the above rule.

Here's my C++ code:

```
int main() {
int a, b, pow, first = 0, second = 0;
cin >> a >> b;
for(int i = a; i < b; i++) {
    pow = i*i;
    first = (i*i)/10;
    second = (i*i)%10;
    if(i > 0 && i < 100000 && ((first + second) == i)) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

The thing is this works only on 9:

- 9*9 = 81
- 8 + 1 = 9 (Respects Kaprekar rule)

and my problem is how to solve this algorithm and split in the right way when i have a big number like 2223:

- 2223*2223 = 4941729
- 494 + 1729 = 2223

because the way i solved it with first and second works only on numbers with 2 characters.

Comment: You just have to have an inner loop over places to try to split it.  And you can split it with `pow/k` and `pow%k` where `k` is a power of 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporating the helpful comment of @btilly, you could do it like this:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long long a, b, pow, first = 0, second = 0;
    cin >> a >> b;
    for (unsigned long long i = a; i < b; i++) {
        pow = i*i;
        for (unsigned unsigned long long j = 1; j <= 100000 *100000 ; j = j * 10)
        {
            first = floor(pow / j);
            second = pow % j;
            if (second >0 && i > 0 && i < 100000 && ((first + second) == i)) 
            {
                cout << i << endl;
                j = 100000 *100000 + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think it is important to make sure that the division `pow/j` is always rounded down. Once you have found a fit, the inner loop can be exited.

Comment: It works fine, but something is wrong, he will print 10 too.

Comment: @RobertN. Well 10*10=100 and can be split as 10+0. That fulfils your criteria, does it not?

Comment: Actually it's not, after Kaprekar`s rule, both splitted parts must be non-negative integers.

Comment: @RobertN. Ok, well then we just add two more conditions, see my edited post.

Comment: Yes, that was obvious but still i dont understand why dont print 1 anymore. For loops seems to be alright.

Comment: @RobertN. I don't understand. 1 can't be split according to these rules, right?

Comment: 1 is a big exception here, because 1*1 = 1 -> 1 = 1, there is only one part here, which is positive. It should work for 1 too.

Comment: @RobertN. Yes ok, so I think the first number can actually be zero. Again, I have updated the answer. Hope it works now :-)

Comment: True, it works fine now, but there is still one more trick, it counts only to 9999, so we have a lot more numbers after 9999, like 17344 or 22222 or 95121, even 99999 should be printed, but the last printed is 9999. This example is for interval 1 to 99999.

Comment: @RobertN. Yeah in principle you just have to increase the limits, but you have to be aware of overflows. I have updated the code with long long types and increased limits. It now prints up to 99999.

Comment: Fine now, but it has to print 99999 too, and i dont understand why it is not printing 99999 too, it seems to be alright the increases,

Comment: U have interval 1 to 99999 ?  Edit: It seems you have 1 to 100000

Comment: @RobertN. No, I use the interval 1 to 100000, since you are restricting `i < b` in your outer for loop. But yeah just change that to `i<=b` if that is bothering you.

Comment: True. Thanks a lot for your time and your help.

Comment: There is one more thing, if u dont mind. The correct output for interval 1 to 99999 should have 21 numbers, so it added me some incorrect numbers like: 4879 . Still dont know what`s wrong with that case.

Comment: This is the correct output: 1 9 45 55 99 297 703 999 2223 2728 4950 5050 7272 7777 9999 17344 22222 77778 82656 95121 99999                   and my output is: 1 9 45 55 99 297 703 999 2223 2728 4879 4950 5050 5292 7272 7777 9999 17344 22222 38962 77778 82656 95121 99999     as you can see, there are 3 more numbers who shoudnt be.

Comment: Are you sure about the "correct" output. According to Wikipedia, the numbers 4879, 5292 and 38962  are part of the Keprekar numbers (base 10) and I just verified it by hand for 4879 as well....

Comment: The problem states that the right part should have exactly d digits (counting leading zeros). In this case the original number 4879 has d=4 digits. That said, the right part should also have d=4 digits: 2380,4641. The number 04641 has 5 digits and obviously 4 != 5.

Comment: @RobertN. Well ok. You can calculate the number of digits of your number to check: `unsigned int number_digits_i = floor(log10(i))+1;` and the square number `unsigned int number_digits_square = floor(log10(square)) + 1;` and of the left part `unsigned int number_digits_first = floor(log10(first)) + 1;` and then add the condition `number_digits_square - number_digits_first == number_digits_i` to the if clause. Be aware that directly checking the right part is not possible, because of possible trailing zeros. Also I have changed the variable pow here to square to avoid complications with math.h

Comment: Finally worked. Thank you very much again for your time and help.